# How to insert a label under a input type="text"

Tags: html, css

I've two textbox in a form and i want to insert two label under both of them, to explain better here there is a little drawing of what I want to do:

```
(input1)<--space-->(input2)
<label1><--space--><label2>
```

How can I do this?

edit1:

I'havent't provide further informations, I'm trying to do this just with html and here there's what I've tryied:

```
<div><input name="city" type="text" value="" /> <input name="state"
 type="text" value=""/></div> <label  style="color:grey;"
 >city</label>&nbsp;<label  style="color:grey;" >state</label></div>
```

Comment: Are you looking for a JavaScript way of doing this? Your question is very vague. Plus you haven't shown us what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/kmbxawdd/3/

Maybe you're looking for something like that

```
.input-field {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.input-field label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
}
```